# Getting a scroll bar in Ext JS with a border layout

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to get a scroll bar for the entire window using the ExtJS 5.0 framework. The problem I'm currently having is that the browser window cuts off the page.

I've tried googling the solution to see if I could get it to work with the border layout, but I'm not having any success. I tried inserting the "scrollable: true," config into the parent container but that doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Here is my code for Main.js (where my homepage currently is at the moment and the main view of the app).

```
/**
 * This class is the main view for the application. It is specified in app.js as the
 * "autoCreateViewport" property. That setting automatically applies the "viewport"
 * plugin to promote that instance of this class to the body element.
 *
 * TODO - Replace this content of this view to suite the needs of your application.
 */
Ext.define('QCQA.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    requires: [
        'QCQA.view.main.MainController',
        'QCQA.view.main.MainModel'
    ],

    xtype: 'app-main',
    controller: 'main',
    viewModel: {
        type: 'main'
    },

    layout: {
        type: 'border'
    },
    scrollable: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [
        // HEADER
        {
            region: 'north',
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'container',
            loader: {
                url: 'app/templates/qcqa-header.html',
                autoLoad: true
            }
        },
        // NAV MENU
        {
            region: 'north',
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'container',
            loader: {
                url: 'app/templates/qcqa-nav.html',
                autoLoad: true
            }
        },
        // HOMEPAGE BODY START
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            region: 'north',
            items: [
                // HERO SECTION
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    layout: {
                        type: 'hbox',
                        pack: 'center',
                        align: 'middle'
                    },
                    cls: 'qcqa-hero',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'tabpanel',
                            width: 1040,
                            cls: 'qcqa-hero__tabs',
                            activeTab: 0,
                            plain: true,
                            items: [
                                {
                                    title: '<img class="tab-icon" src="resources/images/icon-contractor.png" alt="" class="icon">' +
                                           '<h2>For Contractors</h2>',
                                    bodyPadding: 15,
                                    html: 'A simple tab'
                                },
                                {
                                    title: '<img class="tab-icon" src="resources/images/icon-engineer.png" alt="" class="icon">' +
                                           '<h2>For Engineers</h2>',
                                    bodyPadding: 15,
                                    html: 'Another one'
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                },
                // SITEWIDE NOTIFICATION
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    tpl: '<div class="qcqa-notification">' +
                           '<img src="resources/images/icon-info.png" alt="" class="icon">' +
                           '<span>{qcqaNotification}</span>' +
                         '</div>',
                    data: {
                        qcqaNotification: 'Sitewide Notice, Maintenance Schedule Can Go Here'
                    }
                },
                // BLOG SECTION
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    tpl: '<div class="qcqa-blog">' +
                           '<div class="container">' +
                             '<div class="qcqa-blog__article">' +
                               '<h3>{blog_entry.blog_title}</h3>' +
                               '<p>{blog_entry.blog_content}<a href="{blog_entry.blog_url}" class="qcqa-blog__read-more-link">Read More</a></p>' +
                             '</div>' +
                           '</div>' +
                         '</div>',
                    data: {
                        blog_entry: {
                            blog_title: 'Title of the Latest News / Announcement',
                            blog_content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim adveniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis ist perspiciatis unde omnis ist',
                            blog_url: ''
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        // HOMEPAGE BODY END

        // PEOPLE PROFILES
        {
            region: 'north',
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'container',
            loader: {
                url: 'app/templates/qcqa-people-profiles.html',
                autoLoad: true
            }
        }

    ]
});
```

If someone can point me in the right direction for a solution to this problem, I would highly appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `scrollable` is available only from 5.1. In 5.0, use [`overflowY`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-overflowX) and [`overflowX`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-overflowY).

Secondly, `border` layout container cannot be scrollable by definition because it is supposed to *fit* all its children items in — allocating a portion of the view to each according to their `region`. Still, nothing prevents you from making each individual child scrollable: add `overflowY` / `overflowY` to any of them where required.

Thirdly, note that all your `border` layout items have `region: 'north'`. Read notes on [this doc page](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Border) on how to configure regions properly.